# Format values in list of data frames as percent

Tags: r, format

I want to format data in list of data frames as percentage. The values are factors.

```
df.ls <- list(list(id = c(1,2,3), x = c(4,5,6), works = c(7,8,9)),
              list(id = c(10,11,12), x = c(13,14,15), works = c(16,17,18)))
```

For that, I create custom percentage format:

```
library(scales)
my_perc_format=percent_format(accuracy = .01, scale = 100,
                suffix = "%",decimal.mark = ".")
```

Then I try to apply it to my list, formatting the values as numbers:

```
test=lapply(df.ls, function(x) 
    my_perc_format(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df.ls[[x]])))))
```

Separately this works perfectly, but in lapply it wouldn't:

```
my_perc_format(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df.ls[[1]]))))
```

**Edit:**

[image: This is one data frame from the list]

The values are factors now, but I want to be number when converted to percent, if it's possible.

**EDIT:**

This is another try to convert my data. This time it's as factor. Without `relist()` the output is fine, but not in the wanted structure. With `relist()` I get the wanted structure, but it returns *NA*.

```
df.ls <- list(list(id = as.factor(c("1","2","3")), x = as.factor(c("4","5","6")), works = as.factor(c("7","8","9"))),
              list(id = as.factor(c("10","11","12")), x = as.factor(c("13","14","15")), works = as.factor(c("16","17","18"))))
names(df.ls)=c("list1","list2")

test=as.data.frame(sapply(df.ls, function(x){
  relist(my_perc_format(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x)))),x)
}))
```

Comment: You have a list of lists but not a list of data frames. May you show your expected output?

Comment: Can you explain how does one reach from your input to expected output? You have numbers like 1, 2, 3 in `df.ls` and your expected output has 0.004848 , 0.023653 etc. What is the logic of conversion? Also ,I don't think you are getting your expected output for first list  using `my_perc_format` ?

Comment: this is not the expected output, but the real input. I want the same structure, but in percentage.

Comment: @Mar so something like this? `as.data.frame(sapply(df.ls, function(x) my_perc_format(unlist(x))))` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Please, look at my last edit of the question.

Comment: are you ok to convert all the values of `df.ls` to character along with output ? Or you want to keep both input and output as factors?

Comment: I think that it would be better if both are factors.

Comment: @Mar I added an EDIT in my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Don't subset the list in `lapply` use `x` directly.

```
lapply(df.ls, function(x) my_perc_format(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x)))))

#[[1]]
#[1] "100.00%" "200.00%" "300.00%" "400.00%" "500.00%" "600.00%" "700.00%" "800.00%" "900.00%"

#[[2]]
#[1] "1 000.00%" "1 100.00%" "1 200.00%" "1 300.00%" "1 400.00%" "1 500.00%" "1 600.00%" "1 700.00%" "1 800.00%"
```

To get output as list of dataframes, we can do

```
lapply(df.ls, function(x) {
    vals <- unlist(x)
    data.frame(original = vals, value = my_perc_format(vals), row.names = NULL)
})

#[[1]]
#  original   value
#1        1 100.00%
#2        2 200.00%
#3        3 300.00%
#4        4 400.00%
#5        5 500.00%
#6        6 600.00%
#7        7 700.00%
#8        8 800.00%
#9        9 900.00%

#[[2]]
#  original     value
#1       10 1 000.00%
#2       11 1 100.00%
#3       12 1 200.00%
#4       13 1 300.00%
#5       14 1 400.00%
#6       15 1 500.00%
#7       16 1 600.00%
#8       17 1 700.00%
#9       18 1 800.00%
```

Or to maintain the same structure as original list we can use `relist`

```
lapply(df.ls, function(x) {
   relist(my_perc_format(unlist(x)), x)
})

#[[1]]
#[[1]]$id
#[1] "100.00%" "200.00%" "300.00%"

#[[1]]$x
#[1] "400.00%" "500.00%" "600.00%"

#[[1]]$works
#[1] "700.00%" "800.00%" "900.00%"


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$id
#[1] "1 000.00%" "1 100.00%" "1 200.00%"

#[[2]]$x
#[1] "1 300.00%" "1 400.00%" "1 500.00%"

#[[2]]$works
#[1] "1 600.00%" "1 700.00%" "1 800.00%"
```

**EDIT**

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df.ls, function(x) {
   temp = factor(my_perc_format(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x)))))
   split(temp, rep(seq_along(x) , lengths(x)))
}))

#  list1.1 list1.2 list1.3   list2.1   list2.2   list2.3
#1 100.00% 400.00% 700.00% 1 000.00% 1 300.00% 1 600.00%
#2 200.00% 500.00% 800.00% 1 100.00% 1 400.00% 1 700.00%
#3 300.00% 600.00% 900.00% 1 200.00% 1 500.00% 1 800.00%
```

You can change the column names as needed.

Comment: Would it make sense to write this as a new column and output the whole (new) data.frame?

Comment: But now the list is not list of data frames, but of vectors I think.

Comment: @Mar When you mentioned in your post that `Separately this works perfectly` the output was still a vector so I thought you needed list of vectors. However, I have added an option to convert it to a dataframe or maintain the same structure as the original one. See if it helps.

Comment: The last code worked, but without ``as.data.frame()``. Now I try to change the columns name with the first row ``lapply(data_33, function(x) {
    temp = factor(my_perc_format(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x[-1,])))))
    split(temp, rep(seq_along(x[-1,]) , lengths(x[-1,])))
    names(x) <- as.character(unlist(x[1,]))
    x <- x[-1,]
})`` . It renames them, but returns the old values, not with the percentage.

Comment: @Mar Don't rename them in `lapply`. What names do you want to give? Do `out <- as.data.frame(lapply(df.ls, function(x) {
  temp = factor(my_perc_format(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x)))))
  split(temp, rep(seq_along(x) , lengths(x)))
}))`  and then use `names(out) <- paste0("col", 1:6)` or something like that.